# What are the advantages and disadvantages of the various git modes available for emacs?

Tags: version-control, git, comparison, emacs

I just started using git, and because I tend to live in emacs, I want to use one of the emacs integration packages.  Looking at [this list](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Git), I see that there are a lot of packages available, but the blurbs for each of them don't explain very much about their capabilities, especially since I don't know git very well.

Which git modes for emacs have you used, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried to describe these changes in [my article about Emacs/Git integration](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsGit.html).

There are following major modes: `git-emacs` is basic mode, that provides access to most of commands, but sometime not so handy in use. `Egg` - good mode, but not actively developed (imho).  `Magit` - is most advanced comparing to other modes, and has modular architecture to extend it, so it possible to add different extensions, such as `git-svn`, etc. And it developed very actively with good community, documentation, etc.

All other modes are mostly add-ons to existing modes, or implement only limited functionality, that often available in other modes (for example, `gitsum`'s functionality is available in `magit`)

Answer (score 3):

I started with `egg` as it was said it's a fork of `magit` with some "extra" features. It was quite good but some operations like `clone`, `push`, and `pull` had to be done using shell commands.

Then recently I've turned to `magit` because I've found out that it has nice handling of pushing and pulling. It reports what changes have to be pushed, and if some interaction occurred with a remote repository it reports that some changes are yet to fetch. Also it seems to be still under active development as opposite to `egg` which seems to be abandoned.

I'm quite happy with `magit` now, but I still sometimes fall back to the command line because I'm still learning it. Also I'm not an expert in `git` itself because I started to use it only a year ago.

Comment: Yes, in some days, Egg was better, because magit's development was staled. But last 2 years, magit's development is very active...

Comment: I essentially never push or pull, just stage and commit. Would you still recommend `magit` if I would never use the network features?

Comment: Well, `egg` seems to have nicer log tree than `magit`. Also the major keybindings are visible right in front of you. I have found myself checking out `C-h m` quite often in `magit`. This problem will disappear when I learn to use it, I hope. So for start `egg` is nicer, then I thing you will turn to `magit`. (This path looks exactly like mine :) )